# repositories' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure)'

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

In my project's bouildSrc module using gradle, I have these warnings in the build "`'repositories' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure)`", how i can fix it?s

build.gradle from buildSrc:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Post the required code.

Comment: @JustInCoding done!